# How do I expand my Log Analytics AzureDiagnostics log data

Tags: azure

We have tons of data being collected on a solution we have deployed to Azure. We have enabled Diagnostics logging on every resource and have it all going into a Log Analytics workspace. What we don't understand is why the log entries appear to not have any data in them:

Here is the query I ran to show how much data we have collected in the past 7 days:

```
AzureDiagnostics
| summarize count() by ResourceProvider, Category
| sort by ResourceProvider asc
    , Category asc
```

This produces the results below:

[image: Diagnostics data summary results]

When I run the query below:

```
AzureDiagnostics
| where ResourceProvider == "MICROSOFT.NETWORK" and Category == "ApplicationGatewayPerformanceLog"
```

I get tons of results that look like this:

[image: AzureDiagnostics query results]

Why is there no other data in these log entries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce this scenario. Properly, you check the logs directly from your `app gateway---monitoring---logs` on the Azure portal. You could query these applicationgatewaylogs from your Log Analytics workspace.

First of all, you need to add the `diagnostic setting` from your application gateway and check the box of `send to log analytics`.

Then search your dashboard, select the Log Analytics workspaces. Query the resources from logs.

[image]

Comment: As you can see from my original post, I had tried the query you suggested and all of the returned rows only showed data in the `TimeGenerated` column. When I ran the exact same query today...the results returned had data in many columns. I did not change anything because I already had it configured properly.

Comment: By default, I always get the result directly from my Log Analytics workspaces instead of from app gateway---logs. Not sure the difference, maybe I need to filter some columns when using it from app gateway--logs.